# Firestore How to Add User Document to Collection at Sign-in with FirebaseUI

Tags: firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui

I'm trying to load a new document as `uid` into a Firestore Collection `users` when a new user signs in.

I am using FirebaseUI + VueJS and trying to populate the data using the `signInSuccessWithAuthResult` callback. (If there is a better way, please do tell).

**UPDATE: I refactored the code (below) and at least now an error is thrown by Firebase:**

```
Function CollectionReference.doc() requires its first argument to be 
of type non-empty string, but it was: undefined  Dismiss
```

Below is one of may attempts w/o success. Your help with code examples will be greatly appreciated.

**firebase-config.js:**

```js
import firebase   from 'firebase';
import firebaseui from 'firebaseui'

import { usersCollection } from '@/services/registerFirebase'

export const FBuiConfig = {
    signInSuccessUrl: '/dashboard',
    signInFlow: 'popup',

    callbacks: {
        signInSuccessWithAuthResult: function(authResult, redirectUrl) {
            const userUid       = authResult.uid;
            const email         = authResult.email;
            const displayName   = authResult.displayName;
            const photoURL      = authResult.photoURL;
            const lastLoginAt   = authResult.lastLoginAt;
            const createdAt     = authResult.createdAt;
            setUser(userUid, email, displayName, photoURL, lastLoginAt, createdAt);
            return false;
        },

        uiShown: function() {
            document.getElementById('app-drawer').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById( 'app-toolbar').style.display = 'none';
        },
    },

    signInOptions: [
        firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
        {
            provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            requireDisplayName: true,
            forceSameDevice: true,
        },

        firebaseui.auth.AnonymousAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
    ],

    tosUrl: '/tos',
    privacyPolicyUrl: function() {
        window.location.assign('/pp');
    }
};

function setUser(userUid, email, displayName, photoURL, lastLoginAt, createdAt) {
    const user = {
        useruid         : userUid,
        useremail       : email,
        displayname : displayName,
        photourl        : photoURL,
        lastlogin       : lastLoginAt,
        created         : createdAt,
        calendarEvents: []
    }
    usersCollection.doc(userUid).set(user);
}
```

Comment: Where is the callback used?

Comment: The callback works (I had a 'console.log' before the last edit) in it - it's just not writing to the DB (see the error returned by the Firestone backed above). Did you read code? It's at the bottom if you didn't see it.

Answer (score 0):

`authResult` is not the user but has the user.

`const user = authResult.user;`

And then you maybe want to make sure the login did work:

```
if (user) {
          const userUid       = user.uid;
          const email         = user.email;
          const displayName   = user.displayName;
          const photoURL      = user.photoURL;
          const lastLoginAt   = user.lastLoginAt;
          const createdAt     = user.createdAt;
}

return user != null;
```

There is a good example in the doc, follow this [link](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#example-with-all-parameters-used)